# ROC curve for neural networks

Tags: python, roc, conv-neural-network

I am trying to plot the roc curve for binary image classification problem trained using CNN model. I have used the following python codes but it resulted in error. The command predict_proba(x_test) shows no attribute error. Can you suggest me the correct sequence of codes to get the solution for this. Thanks

```
    predictions = cnn_model.predict_proba(X_test)
    fpr1, tpr1, _ = roc_curve(y_test, predictions[:,1])
    plt.plot(fpr1, tpr1)
    plt.xlabel('FPR')
    plt.ylabel('TPR')
    plt.title('ROC curve')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show the error, tell us what framework(s) you're using, and what the output looks like from your network. Normally, `model.predict()` should be fine

Comment: See my answer to [How can we build a ROC curve for customized ANN Model on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608002/how-can-we-build-a-roc-curve-for-customized-ann-model-on-python/61608248#61608248)