# Plot ROC curve ANN model

Tags: python, neural-network, roc

I am working on my ANN model and trying to make the ROC plot of the results.

My input for the ROC code is the y_test and the predictions.

How the Y_test looks:

```
[0.5875     0.48229167 0.58125    ... 0.54375    0.60729167 0.628125  ]
```

How the predictions looks:

```
[[0.63529354]
 [0.5447516 ]
 [0.5529088 ]
 ...
 [0.5529088 ]
 [0.5894695 ]
 [0.5880237 ]]
```

Part of the code after evaluating the model:

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()

for i in range (len(Y_test)):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(Y_test[i], predictions[:,i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(Y_test.ravel(), hist.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
```

When I try to run the code I get the error:

```
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: continuous format is not supported
```

The error is about the line and the element Y_test[i]:

```
`    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(Y_test[i], predictions[:,i])`
```

What is my problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we build a ROC curve for customized ANN Model on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608002/how-can-we-build-a-roc-curve-for-customized-ann-model-on-python)